# Laravel Sentry login using username instead of email

Tags: laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

I want to make user would able to login using **username** instead of **email**. According to my search i just found if we update Sentry config file from

`'login_attribute' => 'email'`,

to

```
'login_attribute' => 'username'
```

then it will work. But it does not work for me. My login action is:

```
public function postLogin()
{
    $input = Input::all();
    $remember = (Input::has('remember')) ? true : false;
    try{
        Sentry::authenticate([
           'username' => $input['email'],
           'password' => $input['password']
        ],  $remember);
    }
    catch(Exception $e){}
}
```

Any idea will be appriciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Finally the requirement is change now i want to login user with email or username (any one of them). and i got the solution.

```
    $remember = (Input::has('remember')) ? true : false;

    $username = Input::get('email');
    $password = Input::get('password');

    $field = filter_var($username, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? 'email' : 'username';
    try{

        if (empty($username)) {
            throw new Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\LoginRequiredException();
        }
        if (empty($password)) {
            throw new Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\PasswordRequiredException();
        }

        $user = User::where($field, '=', $username)->first();
        if (empty($user)) {
            throw new Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\UserNotFoundException();
        }

        if (!Hash::check($password, $user->password)) {
            throw new Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\WrongPasswordException();
        }
        Sentry::login($user, $remember);
    }
    catch(Exception $e){}
```

Now i can login using email or username. Hope that may help to someone.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are passing an email `'username' => $input['email']` shouldn't it be `'username' => $input['username']`

Comment: Thanks @Helder for you concern. But i am passing username but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Using this format,     

    try {
    $username = Input::get('username');
    $password = Input::get('password');

    if(str_contains($username, '@'))
    {
        Config::set('cartalyst/sentry::users.login_attribute', 'email');

        $credentials = array(
            'email'    => $username,
            'password' => $password,
        );
    }
    else
    {
        Config::set('cartalyst/sentry::users.login_attribute', 'username');

        $credentials = array(
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => $password,
        );
    }

    // Try to authenticate the user
    $user = Sentry::authenticate($credentials, false);

    return Redirect::intended('app/dashboard');

} catch (Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\LoginRequiredException $e)
  {
    echo 'Login field is required.';
}
catch (Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\PasswordRequiredException $e)
{
    echo 'Password field is required.';
}
catch (Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\WrongPasswordException $e)
{
    echo 'Wrong password, try again.';
}
catch (Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\UserNotFoundException $e)
{
    echo 'User was not found.';
}
catch (Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\UserNotActivatedException $e)
{
    echo 'User is not activated.';
    return Redirect::back()->with('failed', 'Login Failed');
}
```